# Intercepting and manipulating browser history with react router history

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I'm trying to intercept history call in react app and manipulate it to change search parameter of url when it tries to route to certain path. I'm successfully on listening but changing location parameters or replacing history (I want to add `?default_param=value`) is not working. It still change location using old parameters. My example code:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createHistory();

history.listen(() => {
  if (
    history.location.pathname === '/path-to-manipulate' &&
    !history.location.search
  ) {

    const unblock = history.block();

    // this one doesn't change current redirection
    history.push({
      pathname: '/path-to-manipulate',
      search: '?default_param=value',
    });

    /* this one is also not working 
    history.replace({
      pathname: '/path-to-manipulate',
      search: '?default_param=value',
    });
    */

    unblock();
  }
});
```

Long time ago there was `history.listenBefore()` https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/379, but it was removed from api and now we have `history.block()`. I tried with and without block, with different combination of replace/push/forward and event changing history.location explicite. Nothing of that would allow me to properly intercept location before change, alter it and execute with new parameter `?default_param=value`.

How to properly intercept location change and change it (location params) before it executes and redirect?

Two more things:

1. I don't want to mess with `<Link to=...>`
   components and implement logic there. I wanted something global that could manage routing on higher level in react app.
2. listen() won't work when entering url in browser, it only works when using routing in app. Is there another way to catch first reference on certain location in react app?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is try to read the default_param value, and if there is nothing I return with `<Redirect to... />`

"I wanted something global that could manage routing on higher level in react app."
Why is it? You want a global solution for a problem which is very specific?
If this problem happens a lot (you need a default param), you can write a HOC which takes a parameter and a default value and either return with a `<Redirect />` or the wrapped component depends on you have the parameter in the url

Comment: `<Redirect>` works like history.push(...), so it will fire LOCATION_CHANGE action 2 times, first time when react redirect to component and second time when <Redirect> is executed. This is not valid option because all connected actions (e.g. calls to api) will fire two times.
What I need is to try to interecept location change before it happens, change parameters in it and execute, so it will be called only once.
...
Also I will have many routes to maintain and alter in this way, and I don't want to end with writing exceptions in component that would link to them. So I need sth more global.

Comment: I'd return with <Redirect > before api calls, or you just use the default param when you have nothing in the url

Comment: But render() is after all connect(mapStateToProps...) executes. Also what I'm trying to achieve is to appear this search parameter in browser url. This is not only about having this parameter as (default) prop.

Comment: in that case I see no other option then use Redirect, if you don't call API, it is not so expensive to rerender a component with one <Redirect />